# Andron CNC data file

Tags: c++, cnc

My goal is to read the status of a CNC machine that uses an Andron controller. There is a data file located on the machine that I want to use to read the status with. However, I have ran into a problem decoding the data file. Most of it is ASCII control characters and some parts are text but the majority of the data being shared is encoded as a string like "¶d]zi". The general pattern of data will read as follows 
START OF HEADING
END OF TRANSMISSION
šÓRzq
ACKNOWLEDGE
2hÿÿÿÿ
START OF HEADING
END OF TRANSMISSION
›ÓRzq
ACKNOWLEDGE
(h©.

I was wondering if anyone could give me some insight into what the coded strings are or how to go about decoding them?

Comment: Twiddling with encoding on notepad++ or other encoding changable text editor. It "might" be encoding issue, but also might be just binary data.

Comment: @Louis Go Unfortunately, I've attempted that already with no success. If it was binary data how would you recommend trying to decode it?

Comment: Then that's another story... unless you know how they encode the binary data. You have to decode how the data layout. The best way should be contacting controller and explain "what you want", instead of ask them how to decode. I'll assume many cnc controller has data query or collecting api. Read that file is just a implementation to achieve "get status". There must be another way.

Comment: I never heard andron so can't help for that. But some famous cnc like Fanuc/Siemens/Mistubishi/Syntec should have api for accessing controller status.

Comment: @Louis Go We have a few Fanuc machines here so I was also going to look into those. Where could I find/learn how to use their API. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ask your maintenance provider or local Fanuc distributor. I recall it's called FOCAS but with different versions.

Comment: Will do. Thank you for all the help.